# How to align fields in tree view odoo?

Tags: python, odoo

I have a tree view with two columns. The first column's text (Numero) is aligned to right and the second is aligned to left. Why is that happening? How can I align the text of the first column to the left? This is the code of the tree view:[image: I would like all texts aligned to left]

```
<record id="planificacion_resultado_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
  <field name="name">Resultados</field>
  <field name="model">utepda_planificacion.resultado</field>
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <tree>
      <field name="numero"/>
      <field name="name" />
    </tree>
  </field>
</record>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tico1993

I think you went through added style to that field and if it does not work then you can use like this way,

> The text is aligned at the left side anyway (fields of type `char` or `text`)

Reasonably, Numeric (`integer` or `float`) fields as `numeric` fields are aligned at the right side, to align them to the left side like `text` fields, using `type="char"` attribute in XML record.

```
<field name="numero" type="char"/>
```

Comment: The type="char" tag is not working, but I change the type of the field in the model.

Comment: Not working for me too, i used the way to edit css file in static folder

Answer (score 2):

As Odoo is using Bootstrap for its styling, you have access to all its [text classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/text/), `text-left` being one of them (which will apply a `text-align: left`):

```
<field name="numero" string="numero" class="text-left"/>
```

Note this does not left-align the column name though. For that you'll need to add some CSS (you can target the `th` element with `data-name="numero"`).

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution for this [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntSq4.png)

create scss and add this

```
.o_list_view .o_list_table thead > tr > th:not(.o_list_record_selector).o_list_number_th {
    text-align: center;
}
.o_list_view .o_list_table tbody > tr > td:not(.o_list_record_selector).o_list_number {
    text-align: center;
}
```

and inherit template

```
<template id="assets_backend_custom" name="assets_backend_custom" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
      <xpath expr="." position="inside">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/scss" href="/modulenam/static/src/scss/style.scss"/>
      </xpath>
  </template>
```

This will centralize both header and fields